# ls outputs multiple columns even if piped to grep with grml's zsh config

Tags: grep, zsh, ls, pipe

I just decided to give zsh a go against Bash and came across some unhandy behaviour about which I couldn't find anything on the net:

If you do a `ls | grep foo` in Bash, the `ls` only contains one file per line so that `grep` only outputs the matching files. It seems like somewhere (and since I couldn' find anything in the config I think it must be the Bash code itself), the `-1` option is passed to `ls`.
zsh however doesn't do that magic: If you pass `ls` without further options to `grep`, it does just that and you also get result's which coincidentally appeared on the same line as a match.

My idea to achieve the Bash behaviour in zsh would have been to detect whether a `ls` output will be piped into `grep` and define something like an alias for such cases.
But I'm not sure how and if that's possible at all.

**Update:** As larsks points out below, Bash doesn't do anything special here and it's really `ls` which is supposed to work that way if the output doesn't go to a terminal.

Nevertheless, here's what happens to me:

```
> ls
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h

bash$ ls | grep b
b

zsh> ls | grep b
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

I've been able to reproduce that on Ubuntu 11.10 with zsh 4.3.11 and GNU coreutils 8.5 as well as on a Debian Squeeze machine with zsh 4.3.10.

**Update 2:** While investigating a bit more, I found out that this error only appears when the [grml .zshrc](http://grml.org/zsh/) is active. There must be something in there which which opens a terminal for the output if it is piped. Does anybody know what to look for?

Comment: For what it's worth, you should be aware that parsing the output of `ls` is [considered a bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By narrowing down to the responsible line in `.zshrc`, I could figure that out by myself:

It's in fact much simpler than some kind of virtual terminal for piping. The error results from line 1477 of [grml's config](http://grml.org/zsh/) which looks like this:

```
alias ls='ls -b -CF '${ls_options:+"${ls_options[*]} "}
```

So the `ls` command obviously isn't called directly, but via the alias. And that one explicitly activates the column output through the `-C` option.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `ls` documentation, this behavior is intrinsic to the `ls` command:

```
`-1'
`--format=single-column'
     List one file per line.  This is the default for `ls' when standard
     output is not a terminal.
```

When piping to another process with `|`, `stdout` should not be a tty.  `bash` isn't doing anything special.

In all of my tests, using `zsh` version 4.3.15 on Linux and `zsh` 4.3.11 on OS X, `ls` behaves the same way under `zsh` as it does under `bash`.  If you really believe you're seeing different behavior, please update your question with (a) the version of `zsh` you're using and (b) a complete example of the problem, showing both the actual directory contents and the specific command line you're using.